# strtod() function from David M. Gay's dtoa.c

Tags: c

I am using David M. Gay's dtoa() function from http://www.netlib.org/fp/dtoa.c to implement the MOLD function in Rebol3 interpreter. It works well, tested under Linux ARM, Linux X86, Android ARM, MS Windows and OS X X86.

Being at it, I also wanted to use the strtod() function from the above source, the assumed advantage being to get consistent results across different platforms. However, strtod calls cause memory protection problems. Does anybody have an idea what might be needed to make the function work?

Comment: If it is not too long, what is the source code of `strtod` ? That is needed to attempt to solve your problem...

Comment: Can you produce a test-case?  Are you in a position to debug this code?  (e.g. run it under Valgrind)

Comment: @Fabien: Unfortunately, the code looks like hundreds (thousands?) of lines, with dozens and dozens of #ifdefs.

Comment: @Fabien: the source is mentioned above, it is 4370 lines

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - actually I cannot produce any test case that works as expected

Comment: @Ladislav: Ok, in that case, the best thing to do is either to send a test-case to the code's author, or simply to debug it yourself...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I asked the question here since I am sure none of the alternatives you proposed is actually necessary. I think that there are many programmers who already used the code and that they can give me an advice what to do.

Comment: @Ladislav: Maybe!  But "memory protection problems" sounds like it's just broken, in which case the author should fix it (or people should avoid using it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to call `strtod` in the appropriate way, especially taking care of the second parameter. That parameter should be the address of a pointer to char, and this is set to point to the first character of the input string not processed by `strtod`. If you pass the pointer instead of the address of the pointer and that pointer is not initialised to something that happens to be writable memory (like `NULL`), you are likely to have a run-time error.

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *endptr, *str;
    double val;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s str [base]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    str = argv[1];
    errno = 0;    

    val = strtod(str, &endptr);

    if (errno != 0) {
        perror("strtod");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (endptr == str) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No digits were found\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("strtod() returned %f\n", val);

    if (*endptr != '\0')        /* Not necessarily an error... */
        printf("Further characters after number: %s\n", endptr);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Actually, I did not make this bug, but another one. Thanks for the encouragement, anyway.